# Split XML file based on first character of a string

Tags: xslt

I would like to split a file in to several files based on the starting letter of an element. For example:

```
 <Employees>      
 <Employee id="1"> 
 <firstname value="Atif"></firstname>           
 <lastname value="Bashir"></lastname>           
 <age >32</age>           
 </Employee>      
 <Employee id="2"> 
 <firstname value="xyz"></firstname>           
 <lastname value="abc"></lastname>           
 <age >32</age>           
 </Employee>      
 <Employee id="3"> 
 <firstname value="abc"></firstname>           
 <lastname value="none"></lastname>           
 <age >32</age>           
 </Employee>      
 </Employees>
```

After applying transformation, the above file should be split into two files because the first character of Employee/firstname[@value] (and group all the data). So for above case first file should be:

a.xml

```
 <Employees>      
 <Employee id="1"> 
 <firstname value="Atif"></firstname>           
 <lastname value="Bashir"></lastname>           
 <age >32</age>           
 </Employee>      
 <Employee id="3"> 
 <firstname value="abc"></firstname>           
 <lastname value="none"></lastname>           
 <age >32</age>           
 </Employee>      
 </Employees>
```

and the second file should be:

x.xml

```
 <Employees>      
 <Employee id="2"> 
 <firstname value="xyz"></firstname>           
 <lastname value="abc"></lastname>           
 <age >32</age>           
 </Employee>      
 </Employees>
```

What is the XSLT code to perform this transformation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Employee" 
                    group-by="lower-case(substring(firstname,1,1))">
  <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, look into `<xsl:result-document>`.

If you are using XSLT 1.0, you need an extension element, such as `<exsl:document>`.

More clues:

- [Using XSLT to output multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122077/using-xslt-to-output-multiple-files)
- [Does libxslt have a feature for splitting a document into multiple documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167912/does-libxslt-have-a-feature-for-splitting-a-document-into-multiple-documents)